# Use upstart to run a ruby script with rbenv install ruby

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv, upstart

I want to run a script with Ruby 2.1.1 installed via Rbenv. Here is my upstart script:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid custom_user
setgid custom_user

script
        cd /home/custom_user/application/ && rbenv shell 2.1.1 && bundle exec ruby script.rb
end script
```

If I run that command logged as the `custom_user` it works perfectly. In the `application` directory I have the `Gemfile`.

Upstart give me the following error message: `script main process (28879) terminated with status 127`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to specify the full path of `bundle`:

```
script
  cd /home/custom_user/application/ && /home/custom_user/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec ruby script.rb
end script
```